actool not including App Icon and Top Shelf Images for tvOS
I'm try to compile the Asset (Assets.xcassets) for tvOS using actool command as below:
Command
xcrun actool --compile "/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Output" "/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Assets.xcassets" --platform appletvos --minimum-deployment-target "12.0" --app-icon "App Icon & Top Shelf Image" --launch-image "Launch Image" --output-partial-info-plist "/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Output/out.plist" "/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Output"

result in terminal
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.actool.compilation-results</key>
    <dict>
        <key>output-files</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Output/Assets.car</string>
            <string>/Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/Output/out.plist</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

What is expected behaviour?
It should generate the Assets.car file including all the App Icons and Top Shelf Images.

What is not working as expected?.
Command generates Assets.car and out.plist at given directory. But, App Icons and Top Shelf Images are not included in Assets.car file. While other icons are there in Assets.car. There is no error in out.plist.

Inputs : placed Assets.xcassets at /Users/abc/Desktop/ACToolTest/ and created Output folder at same location before executing the command.
Systen Information:

Machine  :   MacBook Pro / M1 Pro / 16 GB / 16-inch / 2021 Mac
OS       :   Version 15.1 (24B83)
Xcode    :   Version 16.1 (16B40)

EDIT:
Working fine on

Xcode version : 15.4
OS : SONOMA 14.5 / M2

